# How to convert the Mode::find(id) response in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm accessing a single model and loading its relation using this code below,

```php
return Application::select('id')->with([
  'oneApplicant:id,user_id,first_name,last_name,email', 
  'oneApplicant.referrer:id,parent_id,first_name,last_name,email',
  'oneApplicant.referrer.parent:id,first_name,last_name,email',
  ])->find($id);
```

and the response is this

```json
{
    "id": 200,
    "oneApplicant": [
        {
            "id": 200,
            "userId": 9,
            "firstName": "Mac",
            "lastName": "Lebsack",
            "email": "edicki@example.net",
            "referrer": {
                "id": 9,
                "parentId": 5,
                "firstName": "Aurelia",
                "lastName": "Boyle",
                "email": "uhirthe@example.org",
                "parent": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "firstName": "Dewitt",
                    "lastName": "Bednar",
                    "email": "tluettgen@example.net"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I wanted to convert the response to something like this (couldn't care less about the other attribute, all I need is first_name, last_name & email )

```json
[
    {
        "id": 200,
        "userId": 9,
        "firstName": "Mac",
        "lastName": "Lebsack",
        "email": "edicki@example.net",
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "parentId": 5,
        "firstName": "Aurelia",
        "lastName": "Boyle",
        "email": "uhirthe@example.org"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "firstName": "Dewitt",
        "lastName": "Bednar",
        "email": "tluettgen@example.net"
    }

]
```

I was testing with `map` and `transform` but it doesn't even work and as I understand with the error, my result is not a collection.

Can someone guide me on how to achieve this,

Thanks

Comment: You should use Eloquent API Resources, checkout the documentation for it here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources  In short, it basically acts as a transformation layer that sits between your Model and the JSON response. You can customize the JSON output to however you like.

Comment: Use left join https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins